# Bcrypt error in docker: process.dlopen(module, path.makeLong(filename));

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, bcrypt

I'm trying to run a nodejs application with docker-compose however am getting issues with bcrypt.
Strangely when I run my dockerfile on it's own using
`docker run -p <port:port> imageName <Dockerfile path>`
it works perfectly fine, no issues. When I run my application with docker-compose, I get the following error.

```
web-container | module.js:682
web-container |   return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
web-container |                  ^
web-container |
web-container | Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
web-container |     at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:682:18)
web-container |     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
web-container |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
web-container |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
web-container |     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
web-container |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
web-container |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
web-container |     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
web-container |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
web-container |     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
web-container |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
web-container |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
web-container |     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
web-container |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
web-container |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/models/Jackpot.js:2:16)
web-container |     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

I have tried several things, including running npm uninstall bcrypt & npm install bcrypt in the dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web-container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build: . 
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./node_modules
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    links: 
      - redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis-container
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding the work the image build does, leading to unpredictable results.  I'm not sure if mounting an anonymous volume to a relative path works; if the host's (wrong-architecture) `node_modules` directory is replacing what's in the image, that would cause the error you see.  I'd delete the `volumes:` for the `web:` container.

Comment: I had the same problem. I fixed it adding a `.dockerignore` file to the root of the project with `node_modules` inside. This forced docker not to share the node_modules between the docker and the host machine (which have different OS)